# Unit testing a catch exception without triggering it

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unit-testing, nunit, moq

**Is it possible to trigger a catch clause from outside of a method?**

```
public class SomeClass
{
    public ApiReEntity GetLeadsByPotentialDogAccount(Guid? accountGuid)
    {
        try
        {
            if (accountGuid == null)
                throw new IdentifierIsEmptyExxception("The AccountId not provided!");
        }
        catch (IdentifierIsEmptyExxception exception)
        {
            _validationDictionary.AddError(Exxception.Message);
            return new ApiReEntity()
            {
                ValidationDictionary = _validationDictionary,
                StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.BadRequest,
                Entities = leadsExpanded
            };
        }
    }
}
```

without passing a null accountGuid, how can I assert that *when_identifierisemptyexcception_is_caught_then_adderror_isinvoked* ?

Please note that the system under test is the actual class **SomeClass**

If this is not possible, **how do you unit test the innards of a catch clause?**

Comment: Why are you throwing and catching the same exception? That looks like a smell. Why don't you simply return the `ApiReEntity` if `accountGuid` is null?

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov i've posted only a subset of the method. there are other throws and more catches for each one. is this not good practice?

Comment: No, you should generally avoid it. You don't want exceptions are part of your control flow.

Comment: If you get invalid parameters, return the object which reflects that it was invalid. From the look of your code that object is `ApiResponseEntity`.

Comment: The general rule is that if your code knows how to deal with something, it's not exceptional and you shouldn't throw an Exception.